# Do the recent apps screenshots/snapshot thumbnails in data/system/recent_images get deleted when the app is closed or overwritten?

Tags: samsung, android-10, android-11, recents-screen

I recently discovered how the recent app switching works, and I saw this thread:

[XDA thread here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/op3-is-logging-user-activity-with-screenshots-false-alarm-solved.3731452/) (and there were a few other questions on here on the same topic, but were different questions)

and have the following questions for Android 10 and 11:

1. Do recent background app snapshots (overview) in data/system/recent_images ever get deleted? Since the data/system folder holds sensitive information, and specifically the task overview snapshots that Android takes for the recent app that are saved in data/system/recent_images or data/system/snapshots that are also called the overview or task list I believe, is there a mechanism that deletes these snapshots or overwrites them when an app is closed?
2. Do different launchers affect the snapshots or access them in any way?

Thank you!

Edited for clarity of main questions.